# Floating-point without FPU

Tags: arduino-uno, float

Since a Floating Point Unit (FPU) is not present in Arduino Uno, I wanted to know how float operations are performed. If it is simulated as integer operations, I want to know how exactly the simulation is done.

Comment: Floating point operations are implemented (rather than “simulated”) in software. You can disassemble any program using floats and see how it's done.

Comment: Implementing floating point in software would mean breaking the number into its mantissa and exponent components (represented as integers) and performing arithmetic on them. Is this correct?

Comment: Of course. The splitting is done by [the function `__fp_split3`](http://svn.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/avr-libc/trunk/avr-libc/libm/fplib/fp_split3.S?revision=2191&view=markup).

Answer (score 4):

As I said in my comment, all float operations are implemented in
software. As a simple test, I compiled the following program:

```c++
volatile float x, y, z;

int main(void)
{
    z = x + y;
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler translated the sum operation into a call to `__addsf3`.
This function extends its arguments to `flt40_t` format (non-standard 40
bits float), calls `__addsf3x` to do the 40-bit addition, then calls
`__fp_round` to convert the result into the standard `float` format.
`__addsf3x` also makes a few library calls of its own. In the end, the
addition pulled the following functions into the compiled program:
`__subsf3`, `__addsf3`, `__addsf3x`, `__fp_inf`, `__fp_nan`,
`__fp_pscA`, `__fp_pscB`, `__fp_round`, `__fp_split3`, `__fp_splitA`,
`__fp_zero` and `__fp_szero`.

All these functions are provided by the avr-libc. You can find them in
the [libm/fplib directory](http://svn.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/avr-libc/trunk/avr-libc/libm/fplib/). See for example the files:

- [addsf3.S](http://svn.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/avr-libc/trunk/avr-libc/libm/fplib/addsf3.S?revision=2473&view=markup)
- [addsf3x.S](http://svn.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/avr-libc/trunk/avr-libc/libm/fplib/addsf3x.S?revision=2473&view=markup)
- [fp_round.S](http://svn.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/avr-libc/trunk/avr-libc/libm/fplib/fp_round.S?revision=2191&view=markup)

Answer (score 1):

software emulation. The float is decomposed into sign, exponent and mantissa and then integer operations are used to do the actual math.

Addition and subtraction means shifting the mantissas to a common magnitude, adding/subtracting them and then checking the highest set bit for the new exponent.

Multiplication means adding the exponents and multiplying the mantissas. Division is subtracting.